# Can't get into Virtual machine with putty

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, virtualbox, putty

There are a lot of threads on this...I've been reading them.

Here's what I've got, maybe someone can help. I'm trying to build an OpenWRT image and struggling. I've got a virtualbox machine running alpine. User Root (obviously) and a regular user, M00, created.

Virtual box network settings: 
Network: NAT
Port Forwarding: Name SSH, Protocol TCP, HostPort 2022, Guest Port 22

No problem running ifconfig on virtual machine and getting 127.0.0.1

run ipconfig on laptop and get 192. etc address (no virtual box).

using putty, try to go in as host: 127.0.0.1 Port 22, Port 2022, host M00@127.0.0.1 etc etc to no avail.

If I do anything with port 22 I get a connection refused message. If I do anything with 2022, I get a black cmd screen with the ability to do nothing...no typing, nothing. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the NAT address setting for Virtual Box.  127.0.0.1 is the loopback address and that will not help you. You need a (say) 192.168.x.y address where x is a different subnet to the host 192.168.a.b  (unless you wish to change to Bridged networking.